# Close hole in mesh without loop

Tags: modeling, vertices

I have modeled a plane and the problem is that the bottom of the wing is missing.

[image]

How do I fill this hole in the easiest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the same number of vertices from both sides, press W and choose Bridge Edge Loops.